# How to integrate two different application information (Like slack and SVN)

Tags: spring-mvc, svn, slack-api

In my web application we use SVN to integrate code. For every committed code file we receive message in Slack (Application similar to Skype) which lets the other development team members (in same chat group) about new file committed in the repository.

I wish to know how this functionality works, so that I should be able to notify some code changes or commit to the repository in other application. Anybody, please point me in the right direction or please let me know if I'm not clear about any point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [post-commit hook](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/reposhooks/post-commit/) script which run after every successful commit. Post-commit hooks are commonly used for such kind of notifications.

Here is an [example for integrating Slack with Subversion (VisualSVN Server)](http://blog.catalystlogic.com.au/?p=56).

According to the [Slack API: Community](https://api.slack.com/community) page, there are two tools that you may find useful:

- [slack-integrations](https://github.com/khera/slack-integrations) - Scripts to integrate Slack with subversion and nagios
- [svn-slack-notifier](https://github.com/robertmiles3/svn-slack-notifier) - A simple app to send VisualSVN Server commit notifications to Slack

Both of these tools are open-source so they should help you to understand how Slack + Subversion server integration works.

Comment: Hi @bahrep, thanks for your fast solution! One more thing, could you please tell me how to get the comment set while committing file in SVN with Java?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Java here? SVNKit Java library?

Comment: Not necessarily using Java, but I want to be able to read the comment written while committing file on Linux. Like in this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928023/how-can-i-prevent-subversion-commits-without-comments, I want to compare string in comment. Can I use 'SVNKit Java library' for this?

Comment: By on Linux I mean my SVN server will be on Linux.