# Windows Pre-commit hook to get Log message on Subversion with Tortoise

Tags: batch-file, svn, tortoisesvn

I have SVN and Tortoise SVN installed in my machine. I have created a Batch file".bat".  I am trying to get Log message to validate it that was provided in the UI before commit.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1928036/2819451) answer which was failing with following error.

```
svnlook: E720003: Can't open file 'C:\Users\GOPICH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\svnC891.tmp\format': The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Can anyone guide me what is the issue is (or) is there anyway to achieve the same.

Comment: You provide repository invalid path to `svnlook` and get an error because `C:\Users\GOPICH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\svnC891.tmp\` is not a repository.

Comment: You are working on the SVN-client, but the solution of the answer you linked operates on the SVN-server, I believe. However, you have TortoiseSVN, so you can set the property `tsvn:logminsize` to the root, so the 'OK' button in the commit dialog is grayed out unless the provided message is at least the given number of characters long...

Comment: @aschipfl I want to write the comment to the text file before commit. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow. What comment do you want to write to what text file?

Comment: @aschipfl Comments is nothing but the "Log Message" given while committing the code.

Comment: The log message is already in a file; when you have a (client-side) pre-commit hook script, its third argument is the path to that file...

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with `svnlook log` as it appends the `\format`.

Arguments returned from stderr to the commit failed dialog are known as:

```
path depth messagefile cwd
```

These arguments are printed from using the code in this answer when commit fails.

The 1st and 3rd are .tmp files located in the temp directory. (*The 1st is a list of files to commit*).

The 3rd argument is the message file so you can use that to check if a message is used.

```
@echo off
findstr . "%~3" >nul
if errorlevel 1 echo args: %* >&2 & exit 1
exit 0
```

This causes commit failure if message file is empty else allows the commit to succeed.

Issues:

- Only a single space in message file causes commit failure.
- Only a double space in message file allows commit.

Seems `findstr` pattern could be improved. This could be a personal preference so keeping the [linked answer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1928036/2819451) from the question.

Idea aschipfl shared in comments:

```
@echo off
if %~z3 gtr 0 (exit 0) else exit 1
```

Any character in message file makes the file not zero in size.

AFAIK, stdout is redirected as being a hook script, thus unavailable,
so `@echo off` is possibly not needed.

**Note: Tested with SVN-client** which may be why `svnlook log`
gave me strange results. Thanks to aschipfl for the information.

Comment: `svnlook.exe` cannot be used on the SVN-client but on the SVN-server only. Anyway, instead of using `findstr` you could just use `if %~z3 gtr 0 (exit /B 0) else (exit /B 1)`...